# (Autohotkey) COMObject doest Work, before it was fine. After reinstalling to new OS Windows, now it can't do COM things

Tags: autohotkey

i need some help..

So i'm just messed up because now my script can't run properly after reinstalling new windows. Now my script cannot process COM / Macros commands for Excel automation..

Before, it was able to activate sheet, activate window, etc.
But now it can't.

This is my Code

```
oExcel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Sheets("BJ-01").Activate                     ; activate preferred BJ / Journal Book
oExcel.Range("C" C).Select
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you very much

Comment: It would be a good idea to actually post here the code you need help with.

Comment: okay i have edit and post my code above Sir....